# Ubuntu 18.04 stopped booting

Tags: boot, 18.04, unity, hard-drive

I was using Unity and one day, while I was using my laptop and clicked on the Ubuntu logo, the entire sidebar disappeared. I tried to restart, but the top bar had disappeared too.

So I did a hard reset and my laptop booted but glitched. After that, it didn't boot back. I put the hard drive in another PC and it was fine.

Can anyone help with what's going on?

Laptop's specs:

- HP Pavilion Notebook PC G6-1026se
- Intel Core i3 2310M
- 6GB RAM
- Intel HD Graphics 3000
- 320GB Seagate 5400RPM HDD (SATA)

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a unsupported desktop. A recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for many flavors, however whilst Unity (7) was not a flavor, it was community supported with only 3 years of supported life.  The GNOME desktop on 18.04 is still supported.

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the RAM or the BIOS. Try memtest or give the BIOS a good check.

Comment: yep it was that old ram (2gb) which had issues i tried removing it and it booted. thanks